# jQuery per-property delays

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, timer, settimeout

I've been struggling with this issue for awhile and have decided to ditch the setTimeout approach since I just read creating too many timers is bad. Below is the function to animate a group of objects - which is called on hover. It's currently setup so that all animation settings are passed in from the user and apply to the correct object, then each object is animated on a per-property basis - allowing for control of speed in/out and easing for each property.

The only thing I'm working on now is the delays. I can't use .delay since it isn't queued and I can't use setTimeout (at least in the approach I've taken). Any ideas?

```
function animate_in(e){ 
$(this).find('.captionator_background').each(function(index){ 
// LOOP THROUGH OBJECTS
current_obj = $(this); current_obj.stop().clearQueue();

// 1. LEFT ANIMATION
current_obj.animate({'left':ends_x_set[index]},{duration:parseInt(bg_x_speed_in_set[index], 10), queue:false, specialEasing: {'left':bg_x_ease_in_set[index]}});

// 2. TOP ANIMATION
current_obj.animate({'top':ends_y_set[index]},{duration:parseInt(bg_y_speed_in_set[index], 10), queue:false, specialEasing: {'top': bg_y_ease_in_set[index]}});

// 3. OPACITY ANIMATION
current_obj.animate({'opacity':parseInt(end_opacity_set[index], 10)},{duration:parseInt(opacity_speed_in_set[index], 10), queue:false, specialEasing: {'opacity':opacity_ease_in_set[index]}});

// 4. BACKGROUND COLOR ANIMATION
current_obj.animate({'backgroundColor':bg_color_in_set[index]},{duration:parseInt(bg_color_speed_in_set[index], 10), queue:false, specialEasing: {'backgroundColor':bg_color_ease_in_set[index]}});

}); // END EACH LOOP
}; // END ANIMATE IN FUNCTION
```

Thanks!

Comment: So, `.animate` doesn't use `setTimeout` then?

Comment: No, I had setTimeout wrapped around each current_obj.animate..... line

Comment: What I'm getting at is .animate probably calls setTimeout a whole bunch internally, so one more setTimeout probably won't hurt.

Comment: The setTimeout timers were wrapped around each "current_obj.animate..." line. There are about 15 properties you can animate. They aren't chained, so that per-property speed and easing can be set. All of this is working, but I had to remove the setTimeouts since (I think) the current_obj value was being updated inside the .each loop before the timer was fired - causing the wrong objects to animate. Looking into this I read that too many timers was bad design, and I was looking at somewhere around 15 timers for hover in and 15 for hover out!

Comment: Not quite sure if there is any type of workaround to create a delay for each .animate line (property) without chaining/adding to the jquery queue....

Comment: Ok, the only thing that I could find was to animate a separate CSS property (one that wouldn't throw errors in IE7/8 and one that wouldn't interfere with what the plugin does). The property would be animate without displaying any visible signs of doing anything, then fire the actual animation as a callback :)